# how to get string data from jquery autocomplete box in php using mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner();

    $('#spinner').autocomplete({
        source:'name.php'
    });
    $( "#getvalue" ).on( "click", function() {
      alert( spinner.spinner( "value" ) );
    });
});
</script>

<body>

<label for="spinner">To search name type here:=</label> 
<input id="spinner" name="value"/>
<p>
  <button id="getvalue">Get value</button>
</p>
</body>[1]
```

[image]

Above is the snapshot of the output and i want to get the particular value from this dropdown on **get value** button clicked and above is jQuery code and html code.

Comment: You want filled value on click of  "Get Value" button ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value from the spinner field can be extracted like this:

```
$( "#getvalue" ).on( "click", function() {
    .
    .
    value = $("#spinner").val(); 
      alert(value);
    });
```